# Chartboost showInterstitial inside didInitialize method, failed in 6.5.2 iOS SDK

Tags: ios, chartboost

There is a major issue in **Chartboost 6.5.2 iOS SDK** where initial boot up always getting failed. ie, If we attempt to show an ad inside right after Chartboost initialize delegate method `didInitialize`, ad request always failed.

> Note: It's happening only for the first boot up right after
>   installation. After that everything works fine.

Please check the attached code: This code snippet working fine in 6.4.7 SDK, but failed to show an AD in 6.5.2. I can replicate this every single time for very first launch right after installation.

```
-(void)didInitialize:(BOOL)status{
    if (status) {
        if ([GameInfo info].isPaidVersion.boolValue==NO)
        {
            [Chartboost showInterstitial:@"Initial_Bootup"];
        }
        [Chartboost cacheInterstitial:@"videoAd"];
        [Chartboost cacheInterstitial:@"Gameplay"];
        [Chartboost cacheInterstitial:@"GameOverHomeButtonVideo"];
    }
}
```